# ¿Cómo puedo obtener dmCopies de la estructura DEVMODE en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito obtener el numero de copias que se mandan a imprimir. He intentado muchas cosas pero ninguna funciona. Ahora mismo tengo este código pero openPrinted no funciona y si omito este paso en la linea `dm = (DEVMODE) Marshal.PtrToStructure (pinfo.pDevMode, typeof (DEVMODE));` me arroja la excepción `AccessViolationException`.

Mi código es este:

Estructuras:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct PRINTER_DEFAULTS{
    public int pDatatype;
    public int pDevMode;
    public int DesiredAccess;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct PRINTER_INFO_2{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pServerName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pPrinterName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pShareName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pPortName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDriverName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pComment;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pLocation;
    public IntPtr pDevMode;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pSepFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pPrintProcessor;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDatatype;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pParameters;
    public IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor;
    public Int32 Attributes;
    public Int32 Priority;
    public Int32 DefaultPriority;
    public Int32 StartTime;
    public Int32 UntilTime;
    public Int32 Status;
    public Int32 cJobs;
    public Int32 AveragePPM;

}


private const short CCDEVICENAME = 32;
private const short CCFORMNAME = 32;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct DEVMODE{

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCDEVICENAME)]
    public string dmDeviceName;
    public short dmSpecVersion;
    public short dmDriverVersion;
    public short dmSize;
    public short dmDriverExtra;
    public int dmFields;
    public short dmOrientation;
    public short dmPaperSize;
    public short dmPaperLength;
    public short dmPaperWidth;
    public short dmScale;
    public short dmCopies;
    public short dmDefaultSource;
    public short dmPrintQuality;
    public short dmColor;
    public short dmDuplex;
    public short dmYResolution;
    public short dmTTOption;
    public short dmCollate;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCFORMNAME)]
    public string dmFormName;
    public short dmUnusedPadding;
    public short dmBitsPerPel;
    public int dmPelsWidth;
    public int dmPelsHeight;
    public int dmDisplayFlags;
    public int dmDisplayFrequency;

}

public const int DM_DUPLEX = 0x1000;
public const int DM_IN_BUFFER = 8;
public const int DM_OUT_BUFFER = 2;
public const int PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER = 0x4;
public const int PRINTER_ACCESS_USE = 0x8;
public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
public const int PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER | PRINTER_ACCESS_USE);
```

y la lógica:

```
//INFO PRINTER 
public String SetPrinterDuplex(string sPrinterName, int nDuplexSetting)
{
    IntPtr hPrinter;
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS pd = new PRINTER_DEFAULTS();
    PRINTER_INFO_2 pinfo = new PRINTER_INFO_2();
    DEVMODE dm;
    IntPtr ptrDM;
    IntPtr ptrPrinterInfo;

    int lastError;
    //byte[] yDevModeData;
    //byte[] yPInfoMemory;
    int nBytesNeeded;
    int nRet;
    System.Int32 nJunk;

    //On Error GoTo cleanup

    if ((nDuplexSetting < 1) || (nDuplexSetting > 3) )
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("nDuplexSetting","nDup lexSetting is incorrect.");
    }
    else
    {
        //if no printername provided, check if there is a default printer and use it instead
        if (sPrinterName.Trim() == "")
        {
            PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
            sPrinterName = printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\0";
        }

        //open the printer
        pd.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS;
        int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(pd);
        IntPtr pdPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
        nRet = Convert.ToInt32(OpenPrinter(sPrinterName, out hPrinter, pd));

        if ((nRet == 0) || (hPrinter == IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            return "Error: OpenPrinter";
        }

        //get the size of the Printer Info structure
        GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out nBytesNeeded);
        if (nBytesNeeded <= 0)
        {
            return "Error: nBytesNeeded";
        }

        // Allocate enough space for PRINTER_INFO_2...
        ptrPrinterInfo = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nBytesNeeded);

        // The second GetPrinter fills in all the current settings, so all you
        // need to do is modify what you're interested in...
        nRet = Convert.ToInt32(GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, ptrPrinterInfo, nBytesNeeded, out nJunk));
        if (nRet == 0)
        {
            return "Error: GetPrinter";
        }

        pinfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptrPrinterInfo, typeof(PRINTER_INFO_2));

        if (pinfo.pDevMode == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // If GetPrinter didn't fill in the DEVMODE, try to get it by calling
            // DocumentProperties...

            //get the size of the devmode structure
            nRet = (int)DocumentProperties(IntPtr.Zero, hPrinter, sPrinterName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (nRet <= 0)
            {
                return "Error: DocumentProperties";
            }

            ptrDM = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nRet);

            nRet = (int)DocumentProperties(IntPtr.Zero, hPrinter, sPrinterName, ptrDM,
            IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)DM_OUT_BUFFER);
            if ((nRet < 0) || (ptrDM == IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                //Cannot get the DEVMODE structure.
                return "Error: Cannot get the DEVMODE structure.";
            }

        pinfo.pDevMode = ptrDM;

        }

        dm = (DEVMODE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pinfo.pDevMode, typeof(DEVMODE));
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(dm.dmFields & DM_DUPLEX))
        {
            //You cannot modify the duplex flag for this printer
            //because it does not support duplex or the driver does not support setting
            //it from the Windows API.
            return "Error: You cannot modify the duplex flag for this printer";
        }

        //update fields
        //dm.dmDuplex = (short)nDuplexSetting;
        //dm.dmFields = DM_DUPLEX;

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(dm,pinfo.pDevMode,true);

        //pinfo.pDevMode = ptrDM;
        pinfo.pSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;

        //update driver dependent part of the DEVMODE
        nRet = (int)DocumentProperties(IntPtr.Zero, hPrinter, sPrinterName, pinfo.pDevMode, 
            pinfo.pDevMode, (IntPtr)(DM_IN_BUFFER | DM_OUT_BUFFER));
        if (nRet < 0)
        {
            //Unable to set duplex setting to this printer.
            return "Error: Unable to set duplex setting to this printer.";
        }

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(pinfo,ptrPrinterInfo,true);

        lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        nRet = Convert.ToInt16(SetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, ptrPrinterInfo, 0));
        if (nRet == 0)
        {
            //Unable to set shared printer settings.
            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            string myErrMsg = lastError.ToString();

            return "Error: Unable to set shared printer settings.";
        }
    }
    if (hPrinter != IntPtr.Zero)
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);

    return dm.dmCopies.ToString();

}//End SetPrinterDuplex
```

Solo tendría que recuperar el valor y colocarlo donde debe, pero no consigo obtenerlo. Agradecería cualquier aporte.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que la información sobre acceder a `DEVMODE` es bastante escasa y me ha costado encontrar algo, pero parece que he llegado a conseguir obtener la información que necesitas. No estoy totalmente seguro de que las estructuras que te pongo sean correctas al 100%, ya que he tenido que ir obteniendo datos de varias fuentes. Espero que te funcione.

Primero,debes definir las siguientes estructuras:

`DM`

```
public struct DM {
    short dmOrientation;
    short dmPaperSize;
    short dmPaperLength;
    short dmPaperWidth;
    short dmScale;
    short dmCopies;
    short dmDefaultSource;
    short dmPrintQuality;
};
```

`POINTL`

```
public struct POINTL
{
    
Int16 dmDisplayOrientation;
Int16 dmDisplayFixedOutput;
};
```

`DEVMODE`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal struct DEVMODE
{
    private const int CCHDEVICENAME2 = 32;
    private const int CCHFORMNAME2 = 32;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHDEVICENAME2)]
    public string dmDeviceName;
    public Int16 dmSpecVersion;
    public Int16 dmDriverVersion;
    public Int16 dmSize;
    public Int16 dmDriverExtra;
    public DM dmFields;

    public Int16 dmOrientation;
    public Int16 dmPaperSize;
    public Int16 dmPaperLength;
    public Int16 dmPaperWidth;
    public Int16 dmScale;
    public Int16 dmCopies;
    public Int16 dmDefaultSource;
    public Int16 dmPrintQuality;

    public POINTL dmPosition;
    public Int32 dmDisplayOrientation;
    public Int32 dmDisplayFixedOutput;

    public short dmColor;
    public short dmDuplex;
    public short dmYResolution;
    public short dmTTOption;
    public short dmCollate;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHFORMNAME2)]
    public string dmFormName;
    public Int16 dmLogPixels;
    public Int32 dmBitsPerPel;
    public Int32 dmPelsWidth;
    public Int32 dmPelsHeight;
    public Int32 dmDisplayFlags;
    //public Int32 dmNup;
    public Int32 dmDisplayFrequency;
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, acceder a la información es sencillo:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings print = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
IntPtr pDevMode = print.GetHdevmode();
var devMode = (DEVMODE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pDevMode, typeof(DEVMODE));
Console.WriteLine(devMode.dmCopies);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero aún no devuelve el dato correcto, me trae siempre 0, creo yo por que ´System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings print = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();´ no me trae la información de la última impresión.